# C# back event in button

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, back-button

I'm trying to code a back event in C# into a button click event, but I cant find the right steps. I am using Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: This question is way too ambiguous, are you talking about ASP.NET, WPF navigation, or something else? What are you expecting this back button to do, and what is it doing instead?

Comment: i want it to return to the previous page just like the back button at the top of the browser does....

Comment: i try to use a response .redirect but it validates the page first and i dont want that to happen..i just want it to return just like the back button at the top of the browser..
some one recomended page.previous page but i get an error that says"only assignment,call,ikncrement and new object expressions can be used as a staement" how can i work it ou.?

Answer (score 0):

Use can use the

[Page.PreviousPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.previouspage.aspx)

to get the page that transferred control to the current page.

> When you use the Transfer method or
>   use cross-page posting to transfer
>   processing from one ASP.NET page to
>   another, the originating page contains
>   request information that might be
>   required for the destination page. You
>   can use the PreviousPage property to
>   access that information
>
> If the current page is being rendered
>   as a result of a direct request (not a
>   transfer or cross-post from another
>   page), the PreviousPage property
>   contains nullNothingnullptra null
>   reference (Nothing in Visual Basic).

Comment: am i supposed to put that in the button click method..?
cus i did an i get a blue line under it with the error that says only assignment,call,ikncrement and new object expressions can be used as a staement..

what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

One approach that can be used is to use the javascript history method:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "My Unique Key", "<script>history.go(-2)</script>");

    }
```